# How the compiler and runtime system deal with nested types in java?

Tags: java, jvm, nested-class, anonymous-class, anonymous-inner-class

how compiler knows about nested types like :

- Nested inner classes
- Anonymous class
- Nested Interface

.....etc

Need clearity.......

Comment: your question is not clear. are you writing a compiler? if not, why do you want to know?

Comment: for my understanding........

Comment: pls. spend time on other things like how to use them. not on how compiler finds and differentiates them.

Comment: @Azodious curiosity is a good thing.... (unclear questions aren't!)

Comment: yeah i agree, but answer to this question i see very less useful. but ya, to OP it may be of great use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compiler extracts inner classes and creates separate `*class` file for each one. Inner class name is created as `OuterClassName$InnerClassName`. Anonymous inner classes do not have names, so their names are created as `OuterClassName$1`, `OuterClassName$2`, etc.

Inner classes have special reference to instance of outer class using syntax `OuterClassName.this`.

Since inner classes are compiled into separate class files JVM does not deal with inner classes at all. It deals with regular classes that have "special" names described above.

Comment: +1 It's worth noting that while Java supports nested class accessing private members of the same outer class, the JVM does not.  What the compiler does is adds accessor methods with names like `access$100` to give class access to private fields, methods and constructors of other classes which share the same outer class.  If you see one of these strange methods in your call stack, this is what it means.